# How to find Gender Neutral?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table participants where there are many fields such as name, sex, and etc. I need help finding duplicate names that have both sex's male and female.

SO if I have a name called 'Angel' and we have duplicate rows, how can we use a query to output 'Angel' being that there are lies 1 row rows that has sex = male and another row where the name is 'Angel' but the sex is female?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate over records sharing the same name, and retain names whose distinct count of sex types is 2 (implying both genders are associated with that name).

```
SELECT name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sex) = 2
```

Note that this assumes that only two genders exist in your table.  If this be not the case, you can add a `WHERE sex IN ('male', 'female')` clause to the above query.